# Node code to integrate with gcp/aws bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, cloud, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am trying to create node js code in which i can integrate it with any cloud service for example gcp or aws . So the same code in node js can use to integrate with gcp, aws or any other cloud service to upload media files. Any suggestion how should i start with?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a Node.js Environment using [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/setup). You can implement Google Cloud Storage: Node.js Client using [github documentation](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage).

I would also suggest exploring the [tutorials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/tutorials#node) on node.js for different use cases, as supported by GCP.

Comment: Thank you for the response , but i am trying to write a one code through which i can integrate to any cloud service .

Comment: You can Install the Client Libraries for Node.js for the specific public cloud (GCP/AWS) and setup the environment.

Comment: is there any script to refer through

Comment: I didn't find such scripts that integrate different public cloud bucket. Thanks